# How much 'stronger' is water vapor than carbon dioxide, molecule-per-molecule, over the course of a day, in terms of global warming potential?

Tags: water, electromagnetic-radiation, atmospheric-chemistry, carbon-dioxide

I have read, many times, that water molecules are far more effective than CO2 molecules at trapping heat...

But, the 'relative G.W.P.' value of water vapor (or its 'radiative forcing') is not listed anywhere I can find, and the stated reason (if one is stated) is that water vapor has always been in the atmosphere in substantial amounts, of course, and if it has increased in prevalence recently it is because of increased CO2 levels, not the other way around....

So what is the amount of solar energy trapped/re-radiated by a water vapor molecule, over a very short time period, in direct comparison to a CO2 molecule?

I am very curious....

Comment: Generally compounds are assigned a global warming potential over a 100 year period, probably because the lengthy averaging facilitates understanding and simulation (and likely increases accuracy/precision). It may not make quantitative sense to lower that period to a single day, in which case nobody would bother assigning such a value. Apparently there is already [criticism of even the 20-year GWP being too short a timespan to consider](https://climateanalytics.org/briefings/why-using-20-year-global-warming-potentials-gwps-for-emission-targets-is-a-very-bad-idea-for-climate-policy/).

Comment: @NicolauSakerNeto These 20 or 100 year averages do afaik simply take into account the lifetime of the compound in the atmosphere. That is imo not what OP was asking for. (If I'm right, OP should make that more clear, i.e. strike "over a day".)

Comment: I think what you’re asking is the relative value of the integrals of the IR absorbance spectra at the bottom of this article? https://www.acs.org/content/acs/en/climatescience/greenhousegases/properties.html

Comment: @Karl I understand, and it could be that OP is asking for something like what Andrew suggests. All I mean to say is that, with regards specifically to GWP, the lifetime of water vapour in the atmosphere **is** a major factor to consider, as its mean residence time is only ~10 days (compared to ~5-200 years for CO2), and therefore water behaves rather uniquely (not even counting the radiative effects of cloud formation...). Making a simple comparison of the relative infrared absorption intensities of CO2 and H2O may be somewhat confounding without context.

Comment: Generally is said, water makes 75% of the GH baseline and CO2 25%. Considering lifetime of H2O in atmosphere does not make much sense in GH effect context, as the water content is dynamically kept about the same in global long term view, slowly increasing with the global warming.

Comment: P.S.: As the GH effect baseline is roughly +30 deg C or litttle more, water part of GH effect makes about +22-23 deg C and CO2 part some +7-8 deg C, what about corresponds to the global mean temperature raise with raising CO2 level 0.03% to 0.04%.

Comment: It does not make much sense to calculate it for a single molecule, as there are multiple very variable factors. It would be always an average calculated from the global level and amount of substance in atmosphere.

Comment: @BuckThorn This may have been a mistake; now that I've read everything carefully this may have been a good question for Earth Science SE but it's not really about Chemistyr, is it. The OP was "Last seen 11 hours ago" so they may not have given up entirely...

Comment: @KurtHikes do you want to edit and clarify your question based on comments? If not, I'll just award the bounty to the closest approximation of an answer if one is posted.

Comment: I found the following useful: http://www.realclimate.org/index.php/archives/2005/04/water-vapour-feedback-or-forcing/